# Curved grid - Cycles vs. Eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, bezier-curves, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to create a simple animation moving the camera through a curved tube, which has a .png image (just a grid) mapped on it.

My problem is that I see some differences in the lines when I export on Eevee and Cycles. The lines on Cycles seems to be much smoother.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image: Not smooth lines on Evee]
*Eevee*

[image: Smooth lines on Cycles]
*Cycles*

I've tried using the *Smooth modifier* but that changes nothing. Both images are rendered using the same sampling values.

[image]
*Shader*

**Q:** Do you know how I can get smother lines for that curve (tunnel) when using Eevee?

Comment: Welcome to blender.se. The images seems to be differently mapped, why? Can you show your scene an modifier list?

Comment: also maybe share your object: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've uploaded the file here

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/XeKgg6Z6/

Comment: @vklidu packed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [Subsurf Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html), then the curvature will be the same for Eevee and Cycles, but in Cycles less visible because of different texture mapping.

[image]

Mapping differs because Eevee doesn't support the [*Panoramic* camera type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/cameras.html#panoramic-cameras) (set for Cycles). Eevee is using *Perspective* instead. Should be probably reported as a UI inconsistency.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot!! I've tested what you mean and it seems to work like a charm :)

Comment: If you have a time please post it as a bug. Panoramic set in Cycles appears when switched to Eevee. Title stay Panoramic, but setup is Perspective. My screen it doesn't illustrate (I just switched type in cycles).

Comment: @brockmann Thanks for polishing :)

Comment: You're welcome! @vklidu